# How to make a php script to create a html file?

Tags: php, file, fopen

Well.... I want to know how to make a script to create a html page. So when the script is executed, it will create a new page. Something like this: mydomain.com/test.html . The script should create the test.html page!

Here is my work:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="nick" value="Enter NIck" />
<input type="submit" value="Create" />
</form>

<?php

$nick=$_POST['nick'];      // get the users input

$fh=fopen('$nick' , 'W')    // Create the page
$contents= include 'sys.php';
fwrite($fh, $contents);
fclose($fh);

echo "Redridectring to your page....";

header('Location: $nick');

?>
```

Now, what this code should do is create a page, which is called
$nick. So if the input is "bleugh", the $nick should be $nick="bleugh".
Then it will create the page "bleugh", include sys.php, then header to the 
page. Is this wright? Will it work?

Comment: Eeeeeek. Please don't do that (that way). That's one big vulnerability.

Comment: Redridectring is not wright. may I suggest a spell checker?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use PHP variables that way inside single quotes

Is OK:

```
"{$nick}"
```

Won't Work:

```
'$nick'
```

But am not sure what you're trying to do with "$contents= include 'sys.php';"? Perhaps you want to capture the output of sys.php into a string? Either way, you need to be careful with vulnerabilities you are opening yourself to.

Answer (score 0):

I think your method by creating a file and then redirect to the file is basically okay. Additional comments:

1. Make sure the PHP process has write permission to the folder you write into.
2. Do you really have to include sys.php? You need to write proper html tags into $contents when you really want to create a HTML file.
3. You should perform redirect before outputting any character, so your redirect would not work because it is preceded by an echo operation.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 header('Location: '.$nick.'');
```